# Facebook share URL code not working

Tags: facebook

I realize Share has been deprecated by Facebook, but this is still posted on their documentation:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[url to share]&t=[title of content]

However, the title won't change no matter what I do -- including adding the "og:title" meta and changing the actual title of the page.

Any suggestions on how I can make it possible for people to share my page with a suggested message? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to use the Facebook Javascript SDK, this will give you much more flexibility with what you share.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/